# How to fix Open Quote error message in HTML code?

Tags: java, html

can anyone help me to fix an error in HTML code.
At line 9 i have an error.

```
Fatal Error: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "border".
```

and the piece of code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>some title here</title>
        <link href="../design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url(../Pictures/background.png)">
        <table border=0 width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p align="left" id="textd"><img src="../Pictures/iconeD.png" alt="D Logo" /> D</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br></br>
        <table bgcolor="#e7ebff" border=0 width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
            <tr valign=top>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Try putting **border="0"**  instead of **border=0**. ( mind the quotes ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

or use css like this:

```
table{
   border:none;
   width: 100%;
   border-spacing:0;
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>some title here</title>
        <link href="../design.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url(../Pictures/background.png)">
        <table style="border:0px;width:100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p align="left" id="textd"><img src="../Pictures/iconeD.png" alt="D Logo" /> D</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br></br>
        <table style="border:0px;width:100%;background-color:#e7ebff;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr valign=top>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```